# Obscure Error when Fitting CatBoostClassifier in Python

Tags: python, pandas, classification, catboost

I am receiving an obscure error when attempting to fit a CatBoostClassifier to training data.  I have created a simple dataset below to help illustrate the problem:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Initialize a dataframe
d = {'response': [1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1], 
     'color': ['red','blue','yellow','blue','red','blue','blue','yellow','red','red'], 
     'status': ['open','pending','open','open','closed','pending','closed','open','closed','open'], 
     'age': [45,10,58,22,42,35,55,26,32,59], 
     'income': [95000,40000,100000,55000,70000,60000,45000,75000,65000,90000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Create X and y matrices
X = df.drop(['response'], axis=1)
y = df.response

# Split into train and test data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.2, random_state=42)
```

Now I will attempt to fit the CatBoostClassifier below:

```
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier

cat_features = ['color', 'status']
cb = CatBoostClassifier(iterations=100, random_state=42, eval_metric='F1')
cb.fit(X_train, y_train, cat_features=cat_features, plot=True, eval_set=(X_test, y_test))
```

I am receiving the following error when attempting to fit the model which states `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'SparseDtype'`.  I am not sure I understand what this is referencing or how to correct the issue.  Any feedback into how to address this error would be much appreciated!

I am running python 3.6.8 and currently have pandas==0.23.4 and catboost==0.24.2 installed.

Answer (score 0):

SparseDtype was new in version 0.24.0 of pandas.  Installed the latest version of pandas.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.SparseDtype.html